# Implicit differentiation step details

Tags: calculus

Finding $y''$ if $x^4 + y^4 = 16$.

Implicitly differentiating, we get
$y'' = -\frac{3x^2(y^4+x^4)}{y^7}$

But the values of x and y must satisfy the original equation $x^4 + y^4 = 16$,
so it simplifies to $y'' = -\frac{3x^2(16)}{y^7}$

My question is: Why must the values of x and y satisfy the original equation?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to think about it a different way. There is nothing wrong with the function without substitution: $$y'' = - \frac{3x^2(x^4 + y^4)}{y^7}.$$
But in the context of the fact that it is used to evaluate properties of the function governed by $x^4 + y^4 = K$, if you go and try and plug values for $x$ you have to impose a constraint on $y$ due to the original equation. So you may as well make the simplification right away.

Comment: If they don't, then you aren't on the original graph.  So you will have a second derivative of *something*, just not your original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, that the derivative at a point $x_0$ is the slope of the tangent line at that point of the graph. That point of the graph has coordinate $(x_0,y_0)$, in your case any pair of points in the graph $(x,y)$ satisfies $x^4+y^4=16$